# Does Google Analytics get all my domain cookies

Tags: google-analytics, httpcookie

In this [article](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id) Google want me to set the cookieDomain to my domain name.

But I am using my domain name on other cookies that hold single sign on security tokens.

So do my  domain cookies go to Google Analytics?

I think that would open a BIG security hole.

Can't put single sign on security tokens in browser storage as XSS attackers can get to them.

So how can I stop Google Analytics from getting my domain cookies and therefore my security tokens?

I don't want to increase my attack surface!

Answer (score 0):

your domain cookies are exposed trough `document.cookie` [interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) and so are available to *any* script that is executed in a page context. So not only analytics but literally any 3-rd party script implemented on your pages has an access to your domain cookies.

Comment: but I have marked my cookies as HTTPOnly =true, SameSite = Strict,  Secure = true so how would a third party script get to them